# Form not submitting due to return false or stopPropogation

Tags: jquery

I have a little pop up that sometimes contains links, other times contains a form.

I have it setup and working for the links, but the jQuery is stopping the form submitting.

I can't figure out a way to allow the form to submit whilst still stopping links firing.

jQuery:

```
$('#account').on('click', function() {
    $('#account-options').fadeIn('slow'); 
    $(document).one('click', function() { 
        $("#account-options").fadeOut('slow'); 
    });
    return false;
});

$("#account-options").on('click', function() { 
    return false; 
}); 

$('#account-options a').on('click', function(e) {
   e.stopPropagation(); 
});
```

HTML:

```
{if logged_out}
<li id="account"><a href="/login">Log In</a>
    {exp:member:login_form return="/"}
    <ul id="account-options" class="login">
        <li id="arrow"></li>
        <li>
            <label>Username</label>
            <input type="text" name="username" value="" maxlength="32" size="25">
        </li>
        <li>
            <label>Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" value="" maxlength="32" size="25">                                   
        </li>
        <li>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Log In">
        </li>
    </ul>
    {/exp:member:login_form}
</li>
{if:else}
<li id="account"><a href="/account">Your Account</a>
    <ul id="account-options">
        <li id="arrow"></li>
        <li><a href="">Edit Details</a></li>
        <li><a href="">Add Submission</a></li>
        <li><a href="{path='logout'}">Log Out</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
{/if}
```

The tags are from Expression Engine.

Does anyone know how to sort this?

Comment: Not clear what you're asking.  Do you want the form to submit on click of every `a` or only on click of some specific `a`?

Comment: Ah my apologies. I need the form to submit when a user clicks on the input submit button.

Comment: Does `{exp:member:login_form return="/"}` create a form in the html markup?  If it does not, you simply don't have a form to submit.

Comment: Yes, it does. All the HTML is correct. If I remove the jQuery it submits fine.

Comment: But you are returning false any click that goes in the ul

Comment: Exactly Patsy. What I need is to exclude the form. I tried a few ideas but none worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To stop the default behavior of all links in `li#account`, use the following:

```
$('#account').find('a').on('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // stops links from being followed
});
```

Then, to toggle the fade in (on click of `a[href="/login"]`) and out (on any click outside of `li#account`) of the account options, use the following:

```
$('#account').find('[href="/login"]').on('click', function() {
    // do the DOM lookup just once and cache it, for better performance
    $('#account-options').fadeIn('slow');
});
$(document).on('click', function(e) {
    var target = $(e.target);console.log(target);
    if (target !== $('#account') && target.closest('#account').length < 1) {
        $('#account-options').fadeOut('slow');
    }
});
```

Do not use the second function from your question, as all that does is return false for any click in `li#account-options`, which is what is keeping your form from being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the target element which is part of the passed event object:

```
$("#account-options").on('click', function(event) { 
    if (event.target.nodeName.toLowerCase() === "a") {
        //anchor, cancel:
        return false; 
    }

    //user clicked something else, probably a submit button. Let it go trough.
});
```

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/zRERn/1/).